# jpa cascade persist many to one

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have two JPA entities (Account and Person), with a bidirectional relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS")
@DataCache(enabled = false)
public class Account
{
    ....
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_OWNER", nullable = false)
    private Person owner;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "OWNERS")
@DataCache(enabled = false)
public class Person {
    ...
    @Column(name = "HAS_ACCOUNTS", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "CHAR(1)")
    private char hasAccounts;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<Accpunt> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Account>(3);
    ...
}
```

When I persist a Person, I do not want to persist all the accounts, but when I persist an account, I want to update the person property hasAccounts, so I need to also update the person.

I make the following steps:

- create a Person
- persist the person
- create an Account
- modify the owner (the previously created
- persist the account (and I hope that it automatically merges the Person)

```
Person p = new Person();
em.persist(p);
Account a = new Account();
a.setOwner(p);
p.setHasAccounts('Y');
em.persist(a);
```

and I get this exception:

```
   javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: Person
```

(I use JPA 1.0 with Hibernate).

Comment: JPA1.2 doesn't exist. JPA 1.0? JPA 2.0?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. JPA 1.0 is the version I use. (I was thinking about JSF 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Person p = new Person();
Account a = new Account();

p.getComments().add(a);
p.setHasAccounts('Y');

em.persist(p);
```